# Explanation of regexp multiple lookahead behavior

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Please help understand why `r'\b\w+(?=\d)(?=[A-Z])'` does not match **Python3A**.

It says `r'\b\w+(?=\d)(?=[A-Z])'` search for words followed by a digit and then by a capital letter. **Python3A** consists of a word `Python` followed by a digit `3` and a capital letter `A`. If the statement is correct, then it should match **Python**.

[Multiple Positive Lookaheads](https://blog.finxter.com/python-regex-lookahead-and-lookbehind-a-helpful-guide/)
[image]

Comment: I  would recommend https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html as a better learning experience

Comment: That article looks incorrect (AI hallucinations?). `\b\w+\b(?!ing)` will always match all 5 words in `I love coding in Python`. The correct lookaround to use here is negative lookbehind: [`\b\w+\b(?<!ing)`](https://regex101.com/r/MaqHpk/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't match because you have two lookaheads in the same place, one of which asserts a number, and the other asserts a capital letter. Since there is no overlap between those, one of them can't be true and so the match fails. What you need is just a single lookahead for a digit followed by a capital letter:

```
\b\w+(?=\d[A-Z])
```

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gGm7yp/1)